# Error while querying attendance list of employee having OneToOne user relation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to get my employee attendance list using django-rest-framework but getting this error:

> ValueError at /shifts/api/v1/my_attendance
> Cannot query "sureshemployee@gmail.com": Must be "Employee" instance.

Code:

```
class EmployeeAttendance(ModelDateCommonInfo):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='employee_attendances', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    check_in = models.TimeField()
    check_out = models.TimeField()
```

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='employee')
```

```
class MyAttendanceList(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = MyAttendanceListSerializer
    filterset_fields = []

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = EmployeeAttendance.objects.filter(employee=self.request.user).order_by('-created_at')
        return queryset
```

Comment: And the serializer?

Comment: show your MyAttendanceListSerializer code

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_queryset(self):
    employee_instance = Employee.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    queryset = EmployeeAttendance.objects.filter(employee=employee_instance).order_by('-created_at')
    return queryset
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.